# Get a project source dir in a Gradle plugin

Tags: java, plugins, gradle

First of all sorry if I've missed this in the documentation somewhere.

I'm trying to write a Gradle plugin in Java.

More specifically I need to do this:

```
public class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project>{

    @Override
    public void apply(Project project) {
        project.getSourceDir();
    }
}
```

In other words, how can I, if possible, get the directory where the sources of the project my plugin is run over reside?

Am I correct in my assumption that when the apply method gets called Gradle will already know where the sources are and this location can not change further on?

Thanks.

Comment: I think no.  I have been having this same issue.  println is your friend ;) and I finally got this working by copying the GroovyPlugin from gradle source quite a bit.  My example I am working on is here... https://github.com/deanhiller/webpieces/tree/master/webserver/gradle-plugin-htmlcompiler

Comment: oh and note if you put printlin in that code you will notice that it is called at configuration time not at execution time and things can change between config and exectuion.

Answer (score 1):

Yes because the plugin is applied to a Project per your parameter.  If you "apply" it to two projects then it creates two instances of the plugin and pass your project objects to the apply method.

Comment: You've answered my second question only if I understand you correctly.Do you also know how to get the sources dir?

Comment: I'm assuming when you say sources dir, you want the sourcesets?  If it is, your plugin should define that.  If you look at the code base for java plugin, that is what it is doing.  You can also base/derive it from an existing plugin, if you look at the GroovyPlugin.  It's the plugin that's setting the convention, the java plugin set it to src/main/java 
<br/>
<code>
public void apply(Project project) {
        project.getPluginManager().apply(GroovyBasePlugin.class);
        project.getPluginManager().apply(JavaPlugin.class);
        configureGroovydoc(project);
    }
</code>

Answer (score 0):

Look through the Gradle user guide.

A project has a list of "sourceSet" objects, which you get to with "project.sourceSets".  Each sourceSet has a set of properties.

It's good to browse through [The DSL reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/) to see what properties are available.  Look for "SourceSet".